# Precedence in error responses when requesting ride

Tags: uber-api

Is there any error precedence when requesting ride? If so, is it defined somewhere in the API documentation?

For example, what error would be returned in this particular situation, if user tries to request ride:

- User is already on an existing trip
- Surge pricing is in effect for request product

I would expect error with code `current_trip_exists` to take precedence over `surge` error in this particular situation. That is the case when testing in sandbox.

Comment: I do not believe error precedence is currently documented / defined.

Comment: Any way to validate this with your technical team?

Comment: There is some discussion about the future of error messages but I don't believe there is any imminent publication of error code precedence. Thanks for the feedback and I've added this request to our backlog.

Comment: Would you mind replying as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: no problem! adding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently documentation on error precedence for the Uber API on developer.uber.com. Thank you for this feedback. At this time this is not a priority for the API but these edge cases are interesting and may be something to define in the future.